# doubt regarding creating a visualforce and controller page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am working on a hospital related project,
I want to create a visualforce page containing 3 pageblocksection named `Department` , `Patients` and `Table view of patient records` .

**1.** `Department` Fields: deptno,deptname,deptdoctor,doctorid
**2.** `Patient` Fields: patientname,patientid,patientinfo,patientjoiningdate,patientoutdate
**3.** `Table view of patient records` in 3rd section.

Does anyone know how to create it, Please help.Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Please supply details of what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I created 2 objects named patient,department

then i created lookup relationship between both of them

then i created fields deptno,deptname,deptdoctor,doctorid in department

I created fields patientname,patientid,patientinfo,patientjoiningdate,patientoutdate

i can't able to create relationship b/w vf and controller i am new to salesforce please help me out

Comment: addding some code of what you have already made may help

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend working through the [workbooks](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook/) that SalesForce provide. In this case the "*Build a Custom User Interface with Visualforce*" section which will go through an example of creating a Visualforce page that is backed by a Controller. That should give you enough information to do what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I also recommend you to study the `Workbook` for both [APEX](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/index.htm) And [VIsualForce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/workbook_vf.pdf), And For now you can try this: I have `Department` and `Patient` as objects and `department` as a Master (in any one of master-detail/lookup) of `Patient` as every Patient is Admitted in Any Particular Department and what i think from ur question you want to show Department of a particular patient on a VF page and detailed information of patient in a section and in a Table Then Try below code it may be helpful to you. You can also modify it According to your Requirement...

***VisualForce***

```
 <apex:page controller="Hospitalcntlr">
  <apex:Form >
   <apex:pageBlock >

   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Department">
       <apex:outputField value="{!Dept.Name}"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!Dept.Department_Number__c}"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!Dept.Dept_Doctor__c}"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!Dept.DoctorId__c}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Patient">
       <apex:outputField value="{!patnt.Name}"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!patnt.patientinfo__c}"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!patnt.PatientId__c}"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!patnt.Patient_Joining_Date__c}"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!patnt.Patient_Out_Date__c}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!patntlist}" var="pat">
            <apex:column value="{!pat.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!pat.patientinfo__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!pat.PatientId__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!pat.Patient_Joining_Date__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!pat.Patient_Out_Date__c}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

  </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:Form>
</apex:page>
```

And ***Controller***

```
public with sharing class Hospitalcntlr {
   Public Department__c dept{get;set;}
   Public Patient__c patnt{get;set;}
   public list<Patient__c> patntlist{get;set;}
   public Hospitalcntlr()
   {
      String ids=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
       patntlist=[select id, name,patientinfo__c,Patient_Joining_Date__c,Patient_Out_Date__c,Department__C,PatientId__c from patient__c where id=:ids limit 1 ];
      for(Patient__C pet:patntlist)
        {
           dept=[select id,name,Department_Number__c,Dept_Doctor__c,Doctorid__C from Department__c where id=:pet.Department__C];
        }
    }
}
```